Create an offline (no-internet) network using netplan
I'm trying to create a simple, no-internet (completely offline) network consisting of an Ubuntu server (22.04 LTS). The server will both create a wifi access point and connect over wired ethernet to clients. Nobody will be connected to the Internet; it's just going to be a small offline network. The server DOES need to provide IP addresses over DHCP to any clients that physically connect to the ethernet or that connect over the Wifi.
What I tried
I have the following netplan:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.66.1/24]
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "MySSID":
          password: "mypassword"
          mode: ap
      addresses: [192.168.66.0/24]

What happens
First problem is that, although I can connected to MySSID (from a Mac), and it gets assigned the IP address 192.168.66.192, once connected, I can't ping the Ubuntu server (I tried both 192.168.66.0 and .1). In fact, in this state, the Mac Wifi control panel actually freezes up and something is deeply wrong.
Second problem is that hardwired ethernet connections don't get DHCP addresses assigned. I suspect that somehow NetworkManager's built-in invocation of dnsmasq only listens on the Wifi connection, not on the ethernet connection.
Any ideas? Thanks!
